# serverMethod is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, abp

I am currently working my way through the "Mastering ABP Framework" textbook.  I am trying to get a list of products using the exact code in the book.  I know the issue is on the JS / jQuery side, but I have very limited experience in this area.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var l = abp.localization.getResource('ProductManagement');

    var dataTable = $('#ProductsTable').DataTable(
        abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            order: [[0, "asc"]],
            searching: false,
            scrollX: true,
            ajax: abp.libs.datatables.createAjax(
                productManagement.products.product.GetList),
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    title: l('Name'),
                    data: "name"
                },
                {
                    title: l('CategoryName'),
                    data: "categoryName",
                    orderable: false
                },
                {
                    title: l('Price'),
                    data: "price"
                },
                {
                    title: l('StockState'),
                    data: "stockState",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return l('Enum:StockState:' + data);
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: l('CreationTime'),
                    data: "creationTime",
                    dataFormat: 'date'
                }
            ]
        })
    );
});
```

I get the following warning in the Console window:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: serverMethod is not a function TypeError: serverMethod is not a function

and the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: serverMethod is not a function

Could you please assist with telling me what I am doing wrong and how to rectify it?

I saw several possible solutions, I tried what I knew.  For example I changed the opening function from

$(function() {

to

jQuery(function($) {

but that did not help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I run the jQuery it should get the product data from the database and show it in the table on screen.  I know my HTML is working and it is executing the js file, but it does not return the data.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Information doesn't belong in comments. Your question title should be a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 productManagement.products.product.GetList
```

with

```
 productManagement.products.product.getList
```

Comment: If it's a simple typo, better to comment and flag to close.